# Hash string using SHA-1 and base64 encode

Tags: r, soap, openssl, base64, sha1

How to hash a string using `SHA-1` and `base64` encode? I have package openssl and I can use `sha1` function to has a string but I don't know how to combine `sha-1` and `base64` encode to my string.

For testing purpose, my string is:

```
HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123
```

I need to SHA-1 and base64 encode to output:

```
nuoiyUX6m+irC5rvB4QUSycfHGc=
```

Please could someone kindly advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the `openssl` package, use the following function

```
openssl::base64_encode(openssl::sha1(charToRaw("HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123")))
```

Answer (score 1):

openssl generally operates on a file,basically stdin in a byte stream.

I am passing "HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123" in a form of printf, In a sequence of non-0 bytes (which may or may not form valid characters in UTF-8 or other character set/encoding).

Since the input is passed from the terminal, on a keyboard. The terminal will send corresponding characters (as written on the key label) encoded in its configured character set.

Usually, set in the current locale. You can find that by using a command "locale charmap".

We have to make sure the input is first convierted to UTF-8 and then passed to openssl. that the reason i have used icovn to convert bytes to the corresponding encoding in UTF-8.

So below command can be used to convert our string in sha1 and then base64 using openssl.

```
printf %s "HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123" |  iconv -t utf-8 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little bit late, but try

```bsh
$ echo -n "HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123" | openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl enc -base64
```

This will:

1. Echo the string to the pipe
2. openssl will digest the string using SHA1 algorithm and pipe it
3. openssl will encode the resulting digested string from step 2 into a new string using base64 algorithm

And it will be echoed back to you.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ echo nuoiyUX6m+irC5rvB4QUSycfHGc= | base64 -d | xxd -g 1
00000000: 9e ea 22 c9 45 fa 9b e8 ab 0b 9a ef 07 84 14 4b  ..".E..........K
00000010: 27 1f 1c 67
```

And:

```bash
$ echo -n "HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123" | openssl sha1 
(stdin)= 9eea22c945fa9be8ab0b9aef0784144b271f1c67
```

And:

```c
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char ibuf[] = "HY8&V5EDJO8NYT9C2011-12-13T00:44:02ZTest123";
    unsigned char obuf[20];

    SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf), obuf);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", obuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And then:

```bash
$ gcc -I /usr/local/include/ test.c /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe 
9e ea 22 c9 45 fa 9b e8 ab 0b 9a ef 07 84 14 4b 27 1f 1c 67
```